# Sigmoid function in Logistic Regression

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, sigmoid

```
function g = sigmoid(z)

g = zeros(size(z));

data = load('ex2data1.txt');
y = data(:, 3);
theta = [0;1;2];
m = length(y);
one = ones(m,1);
X1 = data(:, [1, 2]);
X =  [one X1];

zz =  theta' * X';
ztr = zz';
g =  1/ (1 + exp(-ztr));

end
```

No matter what value i give z i am getting a 1x100 matrix with 1 being the first entry and rest are 0s, how is this supposed to work, is this working correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

your function `sigmoid` is not dependent on the input `z` since it is used only in the line `g = zeros(size(z));` and `g` is re-assigned again at the end of the function.